# Using the Craft CMS Element API V1

Tags: php, craftcms

I am trying to use the Craft CMS [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api). Due to an older version of PHP I am using version 1 (there is a version 1 branch).

Per the installation instructions I:

1) Uploaded the elementapi/ folder to my craft/plugins/ folder:

[image]

2) Went to Settings > Plugins from my Craft control panel and enabled the Element API plugin:

[image]

I then followed the setup instructions and created a new elementapi.php file within my craft/config/ folder:

[image]

I currently just have the following in my elementapi.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'api/news.json' => [
      'elementType' => 'Entry',
      'criteria' => ['section' => 'news'],
      'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
        return [
          'title' => $entry->title,
          'url' => $entry->url,
          'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("news/{$entry->id}.json"),
          'summary' => $entry->summary,
        ];
      },
    ],
  ]
];
```

I tried navigating to http://myUrl/api/news.json, but received the following error: The requested URL /api/news.json was not found on this server.

Any ideas what I may be missing or how I can debug this?

Comment: Figured out if I add index.php/api/news.json it works.

Comment: I was just going to suggest that. Are you able to get to other portions of your site without index.php? On a side note (if you don't have it already), this is a great Chrome extension for working with JSON.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en